# Design pattern for executing sequential logic blocks that one feeds the next

Tags: design-patterns

I have an app that have logic units (each unit is a class and all implements the same interface).

I'm looking for a design pattern that you can build a chain of logic units that each unit's output is the input to the next unit and when finish iterating the units you get the final result.

Is there something that fits this description?

**EDIT:**

Allow me to elaborate some more:
Composition Design Pattern seems like the natural fit for my problem.
What I stumble with is that in my problem I have 2 units that each needs to be executed with its own parameters and in addition, the 2nd one needs parameters that only available after the 1st unit finishes.

What I've done so far is to create 2 Unit classes and another class which is a composition wrapper that holds the 2 units and execute them one after the other, I need to figure out the best way to pass the output of the 1st into the 2nd...

Comment: ... composition?

Comment: Yes, Composition seems like a step to the right direction, but I'm still trying to figure out how to design my problem to fit it.

Answer (score -1):

maybe [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Comment: How is this even an answer? Should be a comment. No effort, no explanation, just a "maybe" and a link.